# AngularJS: Automatically inject dependencies for tests

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a lot of tests in my angular app (tested with Karma & Jasmine in Coffee Script), and I always end up writing all the dependencies of my modules like this:

```
  myModule = dependency1 = dependency2 = dependency3 = undefined
  beforeEach inject (_myModule_, _dependency1_, _dependency2_, _dependency3_) ->
    myModule = _myModule_
    dependency1 = _dependency1_
    dependency2 = _dependency2_
    dependency3 = _dependency3_
```

In the long term, this becomes really annoying, because I have to specify all the dependencies of a module again in my tests. And furthermore, when something changes, I have to add the dependency again to that place, so that I can use it in my test.

My question is, if there is any solution, to inject a modules dependencies automatically in my tests, and assign them to the `window` object, to use them in my tests?

Comment: if you dont need to stub or mock any of those dependencies, i dont think you actually need to manually inject them. Just if you wanna spy on certain functions of the modules... else, angular automatically injects the "real version" of the Deps in your Module under test.

Comment: If you want a good test, it must be "standalone". It means it must not depend on any other component, so you have to mock EVERY dependencies. In order to do that, you can look around $provide, which would help you to do this. More, you do not have to manually inject all dependencies, you should retrieve only the one you want to access to.